# Access a private constant from module

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to access a private constant from an included module?

This is what I would like to do:

```
module B
  def access_private_here
    puts MY_CONST
  end
end

class A
  include B
  private
    MY_CONST = 1
end
```

I know that if this constant was public I could do `self.class::MY_CONST`, is there any way to the same with a private cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest writing it like this so you won't have to change anything other than `include B` if you rename `B`:

```
module B
  def access_private_here
    puts self.class::MY_CONST
  end
end

class A
  include B
  private
    MY_CONST = "cat"
end

A.new.access_private_here #=> "cat"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to refer to it from another module:

```
module B
  def access_private_here
    puts A::MY_CONST
  end
end
```

If you do want to declare it as a private constant, which is highly unusual, you need to go out of your way to do this:

```
module A
  MY_CONST = 1
  private_constant :MY_CONST
end
```

At that point it's private, so you can't reference it. As a note, these sorts of things are best shared using methods rather than constants.

Comment: Ruby makes it tough to make any object truly private: `puts A::const_get(:MY_CONST) #=> 1`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland There's no way in Ruby to stop someone really determined to get to the goods, but you can make it annoying.